# Cumulative sum rows in data.frame

Tags: r, cumsum

I have a data.frame like

```
df    
    l a b c
1  Hi 1 2 3
2 Med 3 1 -3
3  LO 2 -1 0
```

And I would like to  calculate its cumulative sum by row  , that is, I want the result to be:

```
df    
    l a b c
1  Hi 1 3 6
2 Med 3 4 1
3  LO 2 1 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: I need a cumulative amount of rows in df

Comment: This should help `t(apply(df[,-1],1,function(x)cumsum(x)))`

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, OP ask to operate a function over rows not over variable group.

Comment: @A.Suliman The OP _changed_ its question.  At the time I marked, it was appropriate.  Even now, it may be a dupe of another question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen maybe is a duplicate, just connected to the correct duplicated question.

Comment: @A.Suliman, As a result, no col = l

Comment: You can do `df[,2:ncol(df)] <- t(apply(df[,-1],1,function(x)cumsum(x)))`

Comment: @A.Suliman, Thank you